# Can't send object to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I wrote a script to test out post and session using ajax to send the object to php so I can store it into session, however, when I click on the button that redirects me into the footer.php, the webpage will echo false. On the network, it says that the objects has been post into storage.php. Don't know why it would say false on the page. Sometimes when I go back and forth between the pages, the console will print out `[{"name":"John","age":17},{"name":"James","age":22}]True`

Would like to know what is wrong with my code.

End to End I like the object to able to post and store it into session.

***header.php***

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src ="global.js"></script>
    <title>Post Experiment</title>
  </head>
  <body>
       <button id ="jButton" onclick="location.href='footer.php'">GO</button><br>
  </body>
</html>
```

***storage.php***

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['json'])){
  $_SESSION['object'] = $_POST["json"];
  echo $_POST["json"];
  echo 'True';
}else {
  echo 'False';
}
?>
```

***footer.php***

```
<?php
  session_start();
  include('storage.php');
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src ="global.js"></script>
    <title>The reciever</title>
  </head>
  <body>
       <?php //echo $_SESSION['object']; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

***global.js***

```
var oject = [{name:'John', age:17},{name:'James', age:22}]

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#showcart').click(function(){
    $('#output').html('sending..');
      var json = JSON.stringify(oject);
      $.ajax({
        method:'post',
        url:'storage.php',
        data:{json:json},
      })
      .done(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
  });
});
```

**EDIT:**
Ok, looking through the network in the browser, I clicked on `Response` and it said

```
    Array
(
    [json] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => John
                    [age] => 17
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => James
                    [age] => 22
                )

        )

)
True
```

However, it doesn't say this in the actual console. I think it suppose to look like this when I echo it out.

***EDIT 2:***

Ok, looking at the Network, the method `POST` on storage says `Array ( [json] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => John [age] => 17 ) [1] => Array ( [name] => James [age] => 22 ) ) ) True`. However, on footer.php, its a `GET` method and prints out `Array ( ) False` the same as the webpage.

Comment: @RiggsFolly `Array() False` is what it would say

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeap, it will print the text `Array()`